# How to Create a multi-column surfacelistbox with images as items using WPF in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I wish to create a multi-column surface list box with images as elements. However I hit a stone wall... The problem I'm having is with the showing of images... I'm trying to create a surface list box as in below format ;

```
[x]    [x]    [x]   ^
[x]    [x]    [x]   |
[x]    [x]    [x]   | ----> yeah this is a side scroll and the [x] are pictures
[x]    [x]    [x]   |
```

Below is the first version of my xaml;(and it works)

```
<s:SurfaceListBox Name="surfaceListBox1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AllowDrop="True" MaxWidth="Infinity"     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" PreviewTouchDown="surfaceListBox1_PreviewTouchDown"     MaxHeight="350" Margin="1,33,-1,0" > 
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="250"     HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </s:SurfaceListBox>
```

Was the original surface list box. Than I edited to ;

```
        <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" ItemHeight="50" ItemWidth="150" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </s:SurfaceListBox>
```

However this time I loose my images within the surface listbox. My adding to listbox function is as following;

```
foreach (string filename in
                   System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\downloaded_images\\" + event_id))
                {
                    try
                    {
                    surfaceListBox1.Items.Add(
                    new MyImage(
                    new BitmapImage(
                    new Uri(filename)),
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename))); 
                }
                catch (Exception tl) { MessageBox.Show(tl.ToString()); }
            }
```

I just can't find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be welcomed.

Oh yeah and the MyImage class is as below ;

```
    public class MyImage
    {
        private ImageSource _image;
        private string _name;

        public MyImage(ImageSource image, string name)
        {
            _image = image;
            _name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _name;
        }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: no i'm not. i just simply can not see the images.

Comment: Why did you edit the original version that worked? The removal of ListBox.ItemTemplate is the main reason why you're not seeing the images.  Why did you take it out?

Comment: because visual studio gave out an error... how is it supposed to be like?

Comment: Error 1 The attachable property 'ItemsPanel' was not found in type 'SurfaceListBox'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing it is because your `WrapPanel` is setting the `ItemWidth` to 150, and your actual `Image` size is 250. Since the image doesn't fit in the displayed area, it isn't displayed.

Try removing the `ItemHeight`/`ItemWidth` restriction on your `WrapPanel` and see if it works.

Also, you're missing the `ItemsTemplate` tag in your 2nd edited version

```
<s:SurfaceListBox>
     <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" ItemHeight="50" ItemWidth="150" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
</s:SurfaceListBox>
```

Comment: I'm only getting the images names such as "blahblah.jpeg". The images didn't come...

Comment: Took another look at your edited code and you're missing the `ItemsTemplate` tag

Comment: I can not put wrappanel within itemstemplate tag because it give an "Error 1 The attachable property 'ItemsPanel' was not found in type 'SurfaceListBox'." error...

Comment: No, your DataTemplate is missing the `ItemTemplate` tag, your `ItemsPanel` tag is fine. See my edit.

Comment: Just one question... It is still only one column how can I make it a multiple?

Comment: Try setting your WrapPanel's Width to something like 800